# Regex that only matches on odd/even indices

Tags: regex, hex, notepad++

Is there a regex that matches a string only when it starts on an odd or an even index? My use case is a hex string in which I want to replace certain "bytes".

Now, when trying to match `20` (space), `20` in "7209" would be matched as well even though it consists of the bytes `72` and `09`. I am restricted to the regex implementation of *Notepad++* in this case, so I'm not able to check the match index as e.g. in Java.

My sample input looks like:

```
324F8D8A20561205231920
```

I set up a testing page [here](https://regex101.com/r/hY8kK7/2), the regex should only match the first and the last occurence of `20`, since the one in the middle starts on an odd index.

Comment: Is there anything that delimits the string start and end?

Comment: Please check if `20(?=(?:\d{2})+|\D|$)` works for you.

Comment: The start and end of the file, i think Notepad++ allows one to match at least the end of the file with \z not sure about the start

Comment: @stribizhev The regex you posted matches all 20s, but sadly also those it should not match (e.g. 7209)

Comment: Please post some input text, it is hard to guess what the pattern can be without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match `20` at even positions inside a hex string:

```
20(?=(?:[\da-fA-F]{2})*$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hM2iP3/4)

I assume the string has no spaces in this case.

In case you have spaces between the values (or any other symbols), this could be an alternative (with `$1XX`-like replacement string):

```
((?:.{2})*?)20
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/hM2iP3/3)

Comment: Why the disjunction at the end? Can't it be simpler, like so: `20(?=(?:[\da-fA-F]{2})*$)`

Comment: @BramVanroy: It is true that `20(?=(?:[\da-fA-F]{2})+$|$)` is equal to `20(?=(?:[\da-fA-F]{2})*$)`. I did not notice the sample input string at the beginning, and was working on something different. That was just the remnants from the previous effort. Thank you for noticing. However, the overhead was just 1 additional single step.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for evens:

```
rx <- "^(.{2})*(20)"

strings <- c("7209","2079","9720")

grepl(rx,strings) # [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: It just matches everything for me, in Notepad++, as well as in Regex101 (https://regex101.com/r/eV7rR9/1)

Comment: Define odd and even -- are you starting your index at zero or one?

Comment: If the index starts at 0, I want my matches to start at an even index (0, 2, 4...), for a 1-index it would be odd.

Comment: Right, it matches the string because there's a 20 at position 20 (even index).  Did you want to capture the whole string, or just the 20?

Comment: I want to capture just the 20 (and every even-indexed 20 afterwards) to be able to replace it afterwards

Comment: Now it only matches the last 20 in my test string, not the first one (see https://regex101.com/r/cN6fE2/1)

Comment: Right, you might need to repeat in a non-capturing group http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what Notepad++ uses for regex engine - it's been a while since I used it. This works in javascript...

```
/^(?:..)*?(20)/
```

...

```
/^     # start regex
(?:    # non capturing group
..     # any character (two times)
)*?    # close group, and repeat zero or more times, un-greedily
(20)   # capture `20` in group
/      # end regex
```

Comment: Your regex just matches the last occurence of 20 for me, even in the JS engine (see https://regex101.com/r/rF7bS1/2)

Comment: It kinda worked by removing the ^, otherwise it would only match the first occurence, even with global on, however it seems to not be completely robust as it breaks here (https://regex101.com/r/hY8kK7/3)

Comment: It will break without an anchor, `^` or `$` is necessary, but without a variable-width look-behind, it makes no sense using `^` as reference point. I chose `$` since look-ahead is not fixed width in Notepad++ regex flavor.